# How do I get rid of a Spotlight suggestion?

Tags: macos, safari, spotlight

You can see in the screenshot below a spotlight suggestion that I don't understand why it shows up, it looks like a Safari icon (as a web search result suggestion), but it actually is a bit different.
I don't understand where it came from, what kind of suggestion it is (file, web search, email?) and most importantly how do I get rid of it?

I know this has to do with Spotlight's "Siri Suggestions", as if I turn that off, it will go away. However, I do want Siri suggestions, I just want to get rid of this music band.
[image]

Comment: My guess is that you have at one time connected to (perhaps indirectly?) that website. If the `Open in Finder` option is available, you may be able to find it & delete it... maybe in your web browser(s) history file?

Comment: Dorcel should be French musical group which song you have (or have listened?) in Apple Music (there is Dorcel in lower left corner under 'Apple Music' section). If you don't want Spotlight to search you Music library then unticking it in settings should accomplish it.

Comment: Hi, it looks like Music in Spotlight is not the problem, it comes from "Siri Sugestions" I've tried deleting Siri conversation history, but it didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Siri Knowledge tidbit, making a search to the web (presumably Wikipedia) about a general artist. Similar to if you typed the name of a sports team, Spotlight would intelligently return current stats and upcoming games.

In this example, I searched for another small artist, PTAF, where you can see a thumbnail of the artist is not displayed because there's not one available from their Wikipedia. When you search a more popular artist, a thumbnail is displayed.

[image: Spotlight Search Siri Knowledge Example]

In your case, Siri seems to have that random tidbit of information about that band without an accompanying Wikipedia page... nice

Comment: Thanks! This brings some light into it, but do you also know how can I stop Siri from particularly recommending this without having to entirely turn of Siri Suggestions?

Comment: @Dan unfortunately as far as I'm aware we're limited by what's offered in System Preferences > Spotlight. From there you can disable 'Siri Suggestions' altogether, which you mentioned not wanting to do. Sorry. You could try ditching Spotlight for Alfred, I have a option + space command to trigger it. Alfred is much more customizable